# Not able to access private preview of Forms Recognizer - missing dropdown values

Tags: forms, azure-cognitive-services

Cannot enter "Location" and "Pricing Tier" while creating for "Forms Recognizer" in Azure portal  Private Preview. These fields are showing empty dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

This is the response from Microsoft: [https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/921556-form-recognizer/status/1874142]

"Neta (Admin, Microsoft Cognitive Services) responded 
This is due to a different Azure subscription used than the one provided in the access request. Please go to the Azure Subscription option in the portal and reply back to the Welcome e-mail with the subscription displayed in the portal when you see the location and pricing empty."